# WCF Configuration - basicHttpbinding

Tags: wcf, endpoint, basichttpbinding

I have problem with basic configuration of WCF. I am working on MobilePhone Application . First I created test desktop appliction which use basicHttpBinding and everything was fine.
Next  I used the same code (Only difference is in ServerReference - In phone I used Two Server Files  generated using NetCFSvcUtil). In Phone Application I am getting Endpoint no Found Exception.
Below I am putting my configuration. I would be grateful for help or suggestions.

Regards.

Exception on Phone side:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost:4444/Service/PhoneService
>   that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details.

**Phone Configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:4444/Service/PhoneService/"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding"
        contract="IPhoneService" name="BasicHttpBinding" />
    </client>



</system.serviceModel>
```

** revelant fragment of Server Configuration**

```
<service name="Server.PhoneService" behaviorConfiguration="Server.PhoneServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Server.IPhoneService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4444/Service/PhoneService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>



//______________________________//

<behavior name="Server.PhoneServiceBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
```

**Configuration in browser **

> PhoneService Service
>
> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to
>   create a client and use it to call the
>   service. You can do this using the
>   svcutil.exe tool from the command line
>   with the following syntax:
>
> svcutil.exe
>   http://localhost:4444/Service/PhoneService?wsdl
>
> This will generate a configuration
>   file and a code file that contains the
>   client class. Add the two files to
>   your client application and use the
>   generated client class to call the
>   Service. For example:

```
C#

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PhoneServiceClient client = new PhoneServiceClient();

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the client config from another device (eg another dev computer)?.

Comment: Hi, I ve tested everything on my laptop - there is no firewall.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by unavailable internet connection.